# Jquery Execute function when location of a frame changes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger a function when the frame of the page changes the location. I can get the frame object but there seems to be no event to bind...
Should be something like

```
$(function(){
    var object = get_mainframe();
    object.locationChange(function(){
           alert('truggered');
        });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can use the `onload` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onload` function in JavaScript will fire whenever the location of the iframe changes and loads:

```
$(function(){
    var object = get_mainframe();
    object.onload = function () {
        alert('truggered');
    };
})'
```